# How std::transform and std::plus work together?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was reading C++ reference and came across std::plus function with an example. Which is pretty straight forward, its simply adds lhs and rhs. The code was:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string a = "Hello ";
   const char* b = "world";
   std::cout << std::plus<>{}(a, b) << '\n';
}
```

output: Hello world

I changed it to

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   int b = 1;
   std::cout << std::plus<int>{}(a, b) << '\n';
}
```

output : 6

Now I made

```
foo vector = 10 20 30 40 50
bar vector = 11 21 31 41 51
```

I called:

```
std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), foo.begin(), std::plus<int>());
```

and it gave 21 41 61 81 101 which I understand it is adding up both foo and bar. But how it was passed to std::plus function?

Comment: Does this not answer your question? I guess you'll have already looked at it or you wouldn't have figured out how to call `std::transform`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::plus<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) is a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses), which is just fancy talk for a class that implements `operator()`.  Here's an example:

```
struct plus {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    auto operator()(const A& a, const B& b) const { return a + b; }
};
```

The [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) you have there is roughly equivalent to:

```
template<typename InputIt1, typename InputIt2, 
         typename OutputIt, typename BinaryOperation>
OutputIt transform(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, 
                   OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation binary_op)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        *d_first++ = binary_op(*first1++, *first2++);
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Here, `binary_op` is the name given to `std::plus<>`.  Since `std::plus<>` is a functor, C++ will interpret the "call" to it as a call to the `operator()` function, giving us our desired behavior.

Comment: It was an example for demonstration purposes not a submission for inclusion to the standard.

Comment: What do you mean by "Normally, this would fail at compile time"

Comment: @M.M If it weren't a functor/if it hadn't implemented `operator()`.

Answer (score 1):

[std::plus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) one of a set of functors provided by the STL.  If your familiar with functional programming, they are a convenience for function composition.  std::plus specifically is a binary operator, so it takes two arguments.  std::Transform will send it elements from the two vectors.  You can also use std::bind to turn binary operators into one argument operators, basically binding a constant to the second argument.

Personally I think std::plus and its like were more useful before the advent of c++11 [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) functions.  Lambda's allow you to define a set of operations to perform on your data without having to deal with binds or std::plus and its ilk.