# What is the meaning of this syntax std::class<>{}(arg1, arg2) in C++?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, std, type-parameter

Examples where I have seen this:

`std::cout << std::plus<>{}(a, b) << '\n';` in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568541/how-stdtransform-and-stdplus-work-together).

`std::hash<T>{}(54879)`

And others, I can't find them right now.

I know that `object{}` or `object()` calls the default ctor, and `object{val}` or `object(val1,val2)` calls a constructor with parameters. And `object<>{}` or `object<T>()` explicitly specifies any type parameter(s) for the object. But what does this mean when all those are used together? I can't find an article or webpage explaining this either, or I may be missing something. What is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201224/why-is-used-to-access-operator-in-stdhash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is the creation of a temporary functor just to invoke its function call operator.
Assuming the class has an overload of the function call operator:

```
template<typename T>
struct myclass {
    int operator()(int arg1, int arg2);
};
```

Then the snippet `x = myclass<SomeType>{}(val1, val2);` does the following things:

1. It create a temporary object of type `myclass<SomeType>` by calling the default constructor due to the uniform initializer `{}`.
2. It then calls `operator()` on that temporary object, in this case supplying `val1` and `val2` as arguments
3. The whole expression returns the result of the function call operator and the temporary is destroyed

One could instead have written the following equivalent code:

```
{
    auto obj = myclass<SomeType>{}; // initialize object
    x = obj(val1, val2); // invoke operator()
}
```

This is useful, for example, if you want to calculate the hash of an object using `std::hash` but don't want an instance of `std::hash` to live for a long time.