# plus<string> predefined functor for concatenation in c++?

Tags: c++, functor

It looks like plus() predefined functor should work for strings as it devolves to using the operator+. However this does not compile.

```
   string one="one", two="two";
   string result=std::plus<string>(one,two);
```

Why?

Comment: Obviously because there's no `main` and missing includes. But in all seriousness, your question would definitely be better if you [edit]ed it to include a [mcve] (i.e. add the includes, chuck in a `main`) AND show the actual error the compiler gives you. Doing so would help people wanting to help you.

Comment: Not at all a duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568541/how-stdtransform-and-stdplus-work-together) should actually answer your question

Comment: it does not. Somebody has to actually answer this one.

Comment: It doesn't work for string for the same reason it wouldn't work for int. You're using it incorrectly.

Comment: ah, oh. my bad. Sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How std::transform and std::plus work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568541/how-stdtransform-and-stdplus-work-together)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::plus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) is a function object and has to be used in the same manner you would use other function objects.

Minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::string one="one";
    std::string two="two";
    std::string result=std::plus<std::string>()("one","two"); //a temp function object created.
    std::cout << result;

}
```

See [demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ff92b58c5f5c309).

Answer (score 1):

`std::plus` is a functor, which means you need to create an object of it:

```
auto adder = std::plus<>{};
auto result = adder(one, two); // result is onetwo
```

For this reason, you'd never use this as you have: you'd always just simply write `one + two`.

But it does mean you can use this in the same way you'd use `std::greater` and the likes: by passing it as a functor which will apply to some container, rather than needing to write your own lambda to add things together.

See [What are C++ functors and their uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses) for more on functors.